# Flask when I wrote app.route('/home') and edited it app.route('/home/') and restore it

Tags: python, flask, routes, trailing-slash

I'm studying **flask**, and got problems.

When I wrote code like this:

```
@app.route("/reference")
def reference():
    return render_template("reference.html", css="reference", records=records)
```

The page http://127.0.0.1:5000/reference was working.

Then I found **'trailing slash'** in flask document.

I wanted to apply it, so I **edited code** like this:

```
@app.route("/reference/")
def reference():
    return render_template("reference.html", css="reference", records=records)
```

It was working too ! http://127.0.0.1:5000/reference/

But **some problems** were coming.

The browser couldn't read my css file (in html link.. href=blabla) with a changed log in python terminal.

```
GET /static/css/style.css HTTP/1.1 << before changing
GET /reference/static/css/style.css HTTP/1.1 << after changing
```

I redirected css file path,

```
href="static/css/style.css"
to
href="../static/css/style.css"
```

And It works.

I wanted to understand how 'trailing slash' do.

So I **reset** my code to first code.

Then **404 not found error** raised and I got a **not changed log**.

```
"GET /reference HTTP/1.1" << log for first code
"GET /reference/ HTTP/1.1" << log for second code
"GET /reference/ HTTP/1.1" << log for reset code (== first code)
```

I got a question. **What is happend?**

I don't understand why it doesn't run like before.

I read https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/quickstart/#unique-urls-redirection-behavior

But I still don't understand what is going on.

Why the GET path changed.. why the GET path doesn't changed.. why..

My mind is broken and I can't sleep.. please help me..

Comment: Did you use the template tag for your CSS URL as described in https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/tutorial/static/ ?

Comment: Yes. In my layout.html, <link rel="stylesheet "href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/style.css') }}" /> is there. The reason I talked about css in the text is because I wanted to talk about one Symptom. because layout.html got another css link. I want to use href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/style.css') }}" to another css, but css arg came from server and I try href="{{ url_for('static', filename='{{css}}/style.css') }}", it's not working. so I have to change my CSS URL like text.

Comment: Actually I want to know why app.route("/reference) works in only first time, not now.

Comment: https://github.com/Do-code-ing/Nomad_Job_Search/blob/master/templates/layout.html

Answer (score 0):

On top of what the `unique-urls-redirection-behavior` document says, when you use tags like `<img src='some_url'>` or `<link href='some_url'>` the behaviour may be different, as these URLs are loaded **by the browser**.

So with a route decorator like `@app.route("/reference")` which loads in the browser as `example.com/reference` a link tag with `href="subpath/file.css"` causes the browser to load that resource from `example.com/subpath/file.css`

On the other hand, with a route decorator like `@app.route("/reference/")` (with the trailing slash) which loads in the browser as `example.com/reference/` (again, with the trailing slash) a link tag with `href="subpath/file.css"` causes the browser to load that resource from `example.com/reference/subpath/file.css`

This could explain the behaviour you are seeing.

---

To put this another way, consider this test app:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/a')
def a(): return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/b/') # Note trailing slash
def b(): return render_template('index.html')
```

Paired with the following template at `templates/index.html`:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel='stylesheet'  href='subpath/file.css' />
</head>
```

Then make some hits and observe the asset requests in the console (they will give 404 errors because I haven't actually created the CSS files, this is just to show what *the browser requests*):

Load URL: `http://localhost:5000/a`:

```
"GET /a HTTP/1.1" 200 -
"GET /subpath/file.css HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

Load URL: `http://localhost:5000/b/`:

```
"GET /b/ HTTP/1.1" 200 -
"GET /b/subpath/file.css HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

Of course the correct way to include these assets is to use the `url_for` function.

So if I update the template to instead contain:

```
  <link rel='stylesheet'  href='{{ url_for("static", filename="file.css") }}' />
```

Then make the same request:

Load URL: `http://localhost:5000/a`:

```
"GET /a HTTP/1.1" 200 -
"GET /static/file.css HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

Load URL: `http://localhost:5000/b/`:

```
"GET /b/ HTTP/1.1" 200 -
"GET /static/file.css HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

As you can see here, the **correct path** for static assets will always be rendered, regardless of whether the endpoint has a trailing slash or not.

Comment: thanks for your answer with url_for behavior. then could you tell your idea to me why app.route("/a") doesn't work when I edited it app.route("/a/") and restore it? Is it a bug? my real question is it.